# center text in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've seen several answers of this sort on StackOverflow, but none of them suit my purposes. What I'm trying to do is center **text** in the navbar. All of the other answers I've seen dealt with centering a nav `ul`. What I want to do is center a `.nav-text` in the navbar. I tried centering the text with `text-align: center` on pretty much every element in the navbar (`.navbar`, `.container`, `.navbar-collapse`) but none of them work.

**HTML**

```
<div id="navbar" style="opacity: 0;">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="text-align: center;">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/">My Website</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              </ul>
              <p class='navbar-text text-center' style='text-align: center;'>My Website</p>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <p class="navbar-btn"><a href="checkout.php" class="btn btn-success">Continue to checkout <span class='fa fa-arrow-right'></span></a></p>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
```

How can this work?

Comment: remove style="opacity: 0;" from main div

Comment: That has nothing to do with the problem, I'm just using JS to make the navbar fade in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way would be to use `position:absolute`. Create a special class for this and add the class to your `navbar-text`.

```
.navbar-center
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/KLxn8UrXFW

Comment: The problem with that is that the `.navbar-text` then covers everything else.

Comment: ? How does it cover everything else?

Comment: Try clicking on the navbar items. It doesn't hide them, but it prevents you from clicking on them.

Comment: Okay, found a workaround: just use `height:0;` and `overflow: visible;`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please consider the z-index in this case, otherwise you can't click the nav menu. Thanks

```
.nabvar-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
 }

.navbar-nav,
.navbar-right {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Forcing float as "none" worked for me. Overrides default float??? Then just text-align: center.

```
  .navbar-text{
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
```